# How many samples required to reduce standard error to a specified figure?

Tags: sampling, standard-deviation, sample-size, standard-error

I have a large batch of product that I am testing for protein content (target = 12%). I know the standard deviation for the test method is 0.6. I want to test a number of samples from the batch, so that I can average these results, reducing the error. I want the error to be 0.1 or lower. How many samples do I need to take?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you mean "Standard Error" rather than "Standard Deviation" in your question title. The standard error is the standard deviation divided by the square root of the sample size. You can use that to calculate the sample size needed for a standard error no greater than 0.1.

Comment: @eipi10 Indeed, so I changed question to reflect content. Your comment was good enough to be an answer, and it appeared while I was filling the answer out. So, not stealing your thunder there, we agree 100%, which is hardly surprising.

Answer (score 1):

$SE=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$,

where $SE=0.1$ is the standard error desired, $\sigma=0.6$ is the standard deviation, and $n$ is the sample size. Then as

$n=(\frac{\sigma}{SE})^2$,

$n\geq(\frac{0.6}{0.1})^2=36$